# ASP.NET MVC Checkbox Group

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I am trying to formulate a work-around for the lack of a "checkbox group" in ASP.NET MVC.  The typical way to implement this is to have check boxes of the same name, each with the value it represents.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="n" value=1 />
<input type="checkbox" name="n" value=2 />
<input type="checkbox" name="n" value=3 />
```

When submitted, it will comma delimit all values to the request item "n".. so Request["n"] == "1,2,3" if all three are checked when submitted.  In ASP.NET MVC, you can have a parameter of n as an array to accept this post.

```
public ActionResult ActionName( int[] n ) { ... }
```

**All of the above works fine.**  The problem I have is that when validation fails, the check boxes are not restored to their checked state.  Any suggestions.

**Problem Code:** (I started with the default asp.net mvc project)

Controller

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {   var t = getTestModel("First");
            return View(t);
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Index(TestModelView t)
        {   if(String.IsNullOrEmpty( t.TextBoxValue))
                ModelState.AddModelError("TextBoxValue", "TextBoxValue required.");
            var newView = getTestModel("Next");
            return View(newView);
        }

        private TestModelView getTestModel(string prefix)
        {   var t = new TestModelView();
            t.Checkboxes = new List<CheckboxInfo>()
            {   new CheckboxInfo(){Text = prefix + "1", Value="1", IsChecked=false},
                new CheckboxInfo(){Text = prefix + "2", Value="2", IsChecked=false} 
            };
            return t;
        }
    }
    public class TestModelView
    {   public string TextBoxValue { get; set; }
        public List<CheckboxInfo> Checkboxes { get; set; }
    }
    public class CheckboxInfo
    {   public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ASPX

```
<%
using( Html.BeginForm() ){ 
%>  <p><%= Html.ValidationSummary() %></p>
    <p><%= Html.TextBox("TextBoxValue")%></p>
    <p><%  
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var cb in Model.Checkboxes)
    { %>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Checkboxes[<%=i%>]" 
            value="<%= Html.Encode(cb.Value) %>" <%=cb.IsChecked ? "checked=\"checked\"" : String.Empty %> 
            /><%= Html.Encode(cb.Text)%><br />
    <%      i++;
    } %></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="submit" /></p>
<%
}
%>
```

**Working Code**

Controller

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Index(TestModelView t)
{
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty( t.TextBoxValue))
    {   ModelState.AddModelError("TextBoxValue", "TextBoxValue required.");
        return View(t); 
    }
    var newView = getTestModel("Next");
    return View(newView);
}
```

ASPX

```
int i = 0;
foreach (var cb in Model.Checkboxes)
{ %>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Checkboxes[<%=i%>].IsChecked" <%=cb.IsChecked ? "checked=\"checked\"" : String.Empty %> value="true" />
    <input type="hidden"   name="Checkboxes[<%=i%>].IsChecked" value="false" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Checkboxes[<%=i%>].Value" value="<%= cb.Value %>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Checkboxes[<%=i%>].Text" value="<%= cb.Text %>" />
    <%= Html.Encode(cb.Text)%><br />
<%      i++;
} %></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="submit" /></p>
```

Of course something similar could be done with Html Helpers, but this works.

Comment: Post the code for your controller.

Comment: As they say in The Matrix; there is no state ;)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473483/asp-net-mvc-and-viewstate

Comment: @magnus: That's a lot to wade through for what is probably a simple problem in the controller.

Comment: Oh, but there is ModelState... just a bit different.

Comment: @Robert Well, it wasn't ment to be an answer, just some information about mvc, modelstate etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know how to solve your problem, but you could define your checkboxes with this code:

```
<%= Html.CheckBox("n[0]") %><%= Html.Hidden("n[0]",false) %>
<%= Html.CheckBox("n[1]") %><%= Html.Hidden("n[1]",false) %>
<%= Html.CheckBox("n[2]") %><%= Html.Hidden("n[2]",false) %>
```

Hidden fields are needed, because if checkbox is not checked, form doesn't send any value. With hidden field it sends false.

Your post method will be:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(bool[] n)
{
    return View();
}
```

It may not be optimal and I am open to comments, but it works:)

**EDIT**

Extended version:

```
<%= Html.CheckBox("n[0].Checked") %><%= Html.Hidden("n[0].Value",32) %><%= Html.Hidden("n[0].Checked",false) %>
<%= Html.CheckBox("n[1].Checked") %><%= Html.Hidden("n[1].Value",55) %><%= Html.Hidden("n[1].Checked",false) %>
<%= Html.CheckBox("n[2].Checked") %><%= Html.Hidden("n[2].Value",76) %><%= Html.Hidden("n[2].Checked",false) %>
```

Your post method will be:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(CheckedValue[] n)
{
    return View();
}

public class CheckedValue
{
     public bool Checked { get; set; }
     public bool Value { get; set; }
}
```

I wrote it without VS, so it may need little correction.

Comment: I could do something to that effect, though I would have to bind that to the value list. As in the examples in the question, I need to know that [0] is 1 or in the real case, 79 or whatever. I suppose I could handle that with storing the value list is session.

Comment: Bingo!  good thinking.  I had forgotten a couple things... 1. to reference .Value and 2. that when you have any part of an array with a posted value, the binder will create the object at the position.  If you skip an index, it won't create any past the skip.

Answer (score 6):

Behold the final solution:

```
public static class Helpers
{
    public static string CheckboxGroup<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> propertySelector, int value) where TProperty: IEnumerable<int>
    {
        var groupName = GetPropertyName(propertySelector);
        var modelValues = propertySelector.Compile().Invoke(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model);

        var svalue = value.ToString();
        var builder = new TagBuilder("input");
        builder.GenerateId(groupName);
        builder.Attributes.Add("type", "checkbox");
        builder.Attributes.Add("name", groupName);
        builder.Attributes.Add("value", svalue);
        var contextValues = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.GetValues(groupName);
        if ((contextValues != null && contextValues.Contains(svalue)) || (modelValues != null && modelValues.Contains(value)))
        {
            builder.Attributes.Add("checked", null);
        }
        return builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
    }

    private static string GetPropertyName<T, TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> propertySelector)
    {
        var body = propertySelector.Body.ToString();
        var firstIndex = body.IndexOf('.') + 1;
        return body.Substring(firstIndex);
    }
}
```

And in your view:

```
                        <%= Html.CheckboxGroup(model => model.DocumentCoverCustom, "1")%>(iv),<br />
                        <%= Html.CheckboxGroup(model => model.DocumentCoverCustom, "2")%>(vi),<br />
                        <%= Html.CheckboxGroup(model => model.DocumentCoverCustom, "3")%>(vii),<br />
                        <%= Html.CheckboxGroup(model => model.DocumentCoverCustom, "4")%>(ix)<br />
```

Comment: I know this is super old but instead of returning string you should make the return value MvcHtmlString like the other @Html helpers in mvc. Replace `return builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);` with `return new MvcHtmlString(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));` this will output the html and give self closing tags since input's are typically self closing. Great solution though!

Answer (score 1):

Well... the check boxes aren't going to know their state on their own, especially if you are not using the Html.CheckBox helper (if you are, see LuKLed's answer). You're going to have to put the checked state of each box in your ViewData (or Model) and then perform a look-up in your View in one way or another.

**Warning: Really ugly proof-of-concept code:**

Controller:

```
//validation fails
ViewData["checkboxn"] = n;
return View();
```

View:

```
<% int[] n = (int[])ViewData["checkboxn"]; %>
<input type="checkbox" name="n" value=1 <%= n != null && n.Contains(1) ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "" %> />
<input type="checkbox" name="n" value=2 <%= n != null && n.Contains(2) ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "" %> />
<input type="checkbox" name="n" value=3 <%= n != null && n.Contains(3) ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "" %> />
```

All I'm doing here is passing the array n back to the view, and if it contains a value for the respective checkbox, adding `checked="checked"` to the element.

You would probably want to refactor this into an HtmlHelper of your own, or otherwise make this less ugly, of course.

Answer (score 1):

This solution may be of interest to those wanting a clean/simple approach:
[Maintain state of a dynamic list of checkboxes in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291501/asp-net-mvc-maintain-state-of-a-dynamic-list-of-checkboxes/3298821#3298821)

I wouldn't really recommend the use of Html.CheckBox unless you have a super simple, single checkbox bound to a single bool (or a couple of static ones at most). When you start having lists of checkboxes in a single array or dynamic checkboxes, it is difficult to work with and you end up programming the whole world in server side bloat just to deal with the shortfalls and get everything working. Forget it, and just use the clean HTML focused solution above and you're up and running quickly with less mess to maintain in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I know this must be insanely late but just incase anyone else finds themselves here..

MVC does have a way to handle checkbox groups.

in your view model:

[Display(Name = "Which Credit Cards are Accepted:")]

public string[] EmployeeRoles{ get; set; }

On your Page:

```
            <input id="EmployeeRoles" name="EmployeeRoles" type="checkbox" value="Supervisor" 
            @(Model.EmployeeRoles != null && Model.EmployeeRoles.Contains("Supervisor") ? "checked=true" : string.Empty)/>
            &nbsp;<span>Supervisor</span><br />

            <input id="EmployeeRoles" name="EmployeeRoles" type="checkbox" value="Auditor" 
            @(Model.EmployeeRoles != null && Model.EmployeeRoles.Contains("Auditor") ? "checked=true" : string.Empty)/>
            &nbsp;<span>Auditor</span><br />

            <input id="EmployeeRoles" name="EmployeeRoles" type="checkbox" value="Administrator" 
            @(Model.EmployeeRoles != null && Model.EmployeeRoles.Contains("Administrator") ? "checked=true" : string.Empty) />
            &nbsp;<span>Administrator</span>
```

I tried very hard to create these controls with razor but no dice. It keeps
creating that hidden field you all have referred to. for your checkbox group 
you don't need that hidden field, just the code I have added above.  You can create an html helper to create this code for you.

```
    public static HtmlString CheckboxGroup<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> propertySelector, Type EnumType)
    {
        var groupName = GetPropertyName(propertySelector);
        var modelValues = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(propertySelector, htmlHelper.ViewData).Model;//propertySelector.Compile().Invoke(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model);

        StringBuilder literal = new StringBuilder();  

        foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(EnumType))
        {
            var svalue = value.ToString();
            var builder = new TagBuilder("input");
            builder.GenerateId(groupName);
            builder.Attributes.Add("type", "checkbox");
            builder.Attributes.Add("name", groupName);
            builder.Attributes.Add("value", svalue);
            var contextValues = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.GetValues(groupName);
            if ((contextValues != null && contextValues.Contains(svalue)) || (modelValues != null && modelValues.ToString().Contains(svalue)))
            {
                builder.Attributes.Add("checked", null);
            }

            literal.Append(String.Format("</br>{1}&nbsp;<span>{0}</span>", svalue.Replace('_', ' '),builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal)));
        }

        return (HtmlString)htmlHelper.Raw(literal.ToString()); 
    }

    private static string GetPropertyName<T, TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> propertySelector)
    {
        var body = propertySelector.Body.ToString();
        var firstIndex = body.IndexOf('.') + 1;
        return body.Substring(firstIndex);
    }
```

on your page use it like so:
@Html.CheckboxGroup(m => m.EmployeeRoles, typeof(Enums.EmployeeRoles))

I use an enum but you can use any kind of collection