# Display selected check box values in MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a view in MVC3, that has bunch of check boxes. The user checks one or more check boxes and clicks on submit. On submit, I would like to display the checked boxes values in a partial view or a view.

```
<table>
   <tr><td> @Html.Label("Label1")</td><td>  @Html.CheckBox("CB1")</td></tr>   
   <tr><td> @Html.Label("Label2")</td><td>  @Html.CheckBox("CB2")</td></tr>
   <tr><td> @Html.Label("Label3")</td><td>  @Html.CheckBox("CB3")</td></tr>
</table>
 @Html.ActionLink("Submit", "SubmitCB")
```

Controller action:

```
 public ActionResult SubmitCB()
    {
      @foreach (var checked in ?) 
        {
             //Display checked only here...            
        }
    }
```

I was wondering how I can loop through and display the results in a partial view or a view. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your action to allow it to bind to the submitted form.  Also, you need to submit the form properly (I would suggest wrapping it in a form tag and using a submit button as opposed to an action link.  But here's what your action would look like:

```
public ActionResult SubmitCB(bool CB1, bool CB2, bool CB3)
{
    ... // use CB1, CB2, and CB3 here
}
```

If you'd like these checkboxes to be in a list, you need to give them all the same name and different values.  Then You can have your action take in something like `SubmitCB(string[] CBs)` and look at the values in that array (they'll be the values of the selected checkboxes).

Comment: If I have a lot more check boxes than 3, how do I handle this.. cumbersome to have so many checkboxes as parameters?

Comment: Use the second method.  All your checkboxes should have the same name and different Ids.  I usually choose to not use the Html.CheckBox helper for this as it's kind of dumb about it.  But that's your choice.  Just check SO for MVC 3 checkbox list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067786/asp-net-mvc-checkbox-group