# Cannot find Html.Serialize helper in MVC 5 futures

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-futures

I just installed MVC 5 futures in my solution using Package Manager, but I cannot find this helper method ***Html.Serialize***, which was there in previous MVC Futures releases.

**My Question**: What namespace I need to include to start using Html.Serialize helper method with MVC 5 Futures?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently, this extension helper is no longer included in the current MVC Futures.

In my case, I replaced the function call Html.Serialize by [MvcSerializer.Serialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.mvc.mvcserializer.serialize(v=vs.118).aspx) method which is included in Microsoft.Web.Mvc namespace.

To serialize any object in a hidden field:

```
@Html.Hidden("otherComplexData", new Microsoft.Web.Mvc.MvcSerializer().Serialize(complexObject))
```

Later, the controller can turn back the initial object:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(
    IndexViewModel model,
    [Deserialize] DataType otherComplexData
)
```

I hope you find it useful.