# How to serialize an object in MVC 5 Razor view

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, asp.net-mvc-5, formwizard

I have tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402628/multi-step-registration-process-issues-in-asp-net-mvc-splitted-viewmodels-sing) post in order to create a 3 page form wizard that passes data to each page.

He uses the HTML helper `serialize`, to serialize an object in the view.

```
@Html.Serialize("wizard", Model)
```

However this HTML helper isn't available in MVC 5 it seems.

I found another related post to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828553/cannot-find-html-serialize-helper-in-mvc-5-futures) where he suggests using the following to serialize the object.

```
@Html.Hidden("otherComplexData", new Microsoft.Web.Mvc.MvcSerializer().Serialize(complexObject))
```

But I then get the following error

`There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'mode' of 'MvcSerializer.Serialize(object, SerializationMode)'`

It seems to want a SerializationMode, however the documented one doesn't. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.mvc.mvcserializer.serialize(v=vs.118).aspx

What direction can I go in now?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the Serialization option you need:

https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/ASP.NET-Mvc-3/blob/master/mvc3/src/MvcFutures/Mvc/SerializationMode.cs

Options are `Signed` or `EncryptedAndSigned`.

You can try that and see if it will work.

There's multiple ways to encode data that will work for you. You could put the values in a hidden input using `Json.Encode` for the view, and `Json.Decode` on the server side.

Comment: I actually found the class in Futures 5 - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Futures/